# I cannot make this position properly in Wordpress

Tags: css, html

I am trying to write in Wordpress with text and next image and then next paragraph is text and next paragraph is image and in next text. However the second image and text is mixing beside the first image. How will I do this to make it like below. Thank you.

Text
(space)

image
(space)

Text
(space)
Text
(space)

image
(space)

image
(space)

Text
(space)

[image]

Comment: Text (space)

image (space)

Text (space)

Text (space)

image next paragraph(space)
next paragraph
image next paragraph(space)next paragraph

Text next paragraph(space)

Comment: `<p>text</p><p><img src=""/></p><p>text</p><p><img src=""/></p>`
all done in text editor not in html editor

Comment: Thank you for your respond. It is okay in notepad and chrome browser but if I put this in wordpress with <div> tag for  text  it does not move to the next line but instead it is will place beside the image.

Comment: use separate div for each text format and image and be sure that you are using <p></p> inside the div

Comment: @ WisdmLabs, I tried it and this is my code. It's still the same.
<div>Client: Confidential</div>
<div>Project Name: </div>
<div><p><a href="" target="_blank"><img class=" size-full wp-image-668 alignleft" src="" alt="confidential" width="202" height="287" /></a></p></div><div></div>
<div><p><em>     Click image to enlarge</em></p></div>
<div>Client: </div>
<div>Project Name: </div>
<div></div>
<div><p><a href="" target="_blank"><img class=" size-full wp-image-666 alignleft" src=" " alt="Ifugao" width="203" height="289" /></a></p></div>

<div> <em>     Click image to enlarge</em></div>
</div>

Comment: ohk...now use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after image div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the `alignleft` and `alignright` classes defined properly. They should have `float: left;` and `float: right;` respectively.

Make sure you correctly float your elements and clear the floats where you want to start a new row/section.

This is a CSS-only issue.

**EDIT:** Check this solution, note the `clear` and `float` CSS declarations:

```
<div>Client: Confidential</div>
<div>Project Name:</div>
<div><p><a href="" target="_blank"><img class=" size-full wp-image-668 alignleft" src="" alt="confidential" width="202" height="287" style="float: left;"></a></p></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div><p><em>Click image to enlarge</em></p></div>

<div>Client:</div>
<div>Project Name:</div>
<div></div>
<div><p><a href="" target="_blank"><img class=" size-full wp-image-666 alignleft" src=" " alt="Ifugao" width="203" height="289" style="float: left;"></a></p></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div><p><em>Click image to enlarge</em></p></div>
```

Comment: Will you be able to show example for that. Thanks.

Comment: Check my edit. I used your code and added clears and floats.

Comment: Thanks I tried to run it. It's fine. I will try to add more of this. Thanks. :)

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: How will I separate this to make its own in stylesheet.css file. How will I do it? |I run it and noticed the font color is bluish and I cannot find how they made it to that color I want to change it?

Comment: I think this is a different question, and you should first accept the answer for this one (if it works) and then start a new one.

Comment: How will I separate this to make its own in stylesheet.css file.

Comment: You create a new `.css` file in your theme directory, then you call it inside your `header.php`:

`<link src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/yourfile.css" rel="stylesheet">`